# Nothing was returned from render. This usally means a return statement is missing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-camera

I use **React Native Camera** to be able to scan barcodes and right now I'm trying to show a Modal when barcode checks with the item in database.

The error I'm getting is:

> Error: checkBarcode(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.

What should I do to get this working. What am I doing wrong?

**Code:**

```
CheckBarcode(scanResult) {
  const product = DataBase.find((codeMetadata) => {
    return codeMetadata.id === scanResult.data;
  });

  if (this.barCodeRead) {
    if (product) {
      this.barCodeRead = false;
      this.setModalVisible(true);
      return (
        <View>
          <Text>{product.company}</Text>
          <Text>{product.name}</Text>
          <Text>{product.gluten}</Text>
          <Text>{product.ingredients}</Text>
          <Text>{product.id}</Text>
        </View>
      );
    } else {
      this.barCodeRead = true;
      return (
        <View>
          <Text>Produkten finns inte</Text>
        </View>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

**Modal:**

```
<Modal
  animationType="fade"
  transparent={true}
  visible={modalVisible}
  onRequestClose={() => {
    this.setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
  }}
>
  <View
    style={{
      flex: 1,
      justifyContent: "center",
      alignItems: "center",
      backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.8)",
    }}
  >
    <View
      style={{
        backgroundColor: "#fff",
        padding: 35,
        borderRadius: 10,
        width: "80%",
        height: "80%",
      }}
    >
      <View
        style={{
          borderTopWidth: 1,
          borderTopColor: "#000",
          marginBottom: 10,
        }}
      >
        <this.CheckBarcode />
      </View>
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={{}}
          onPress={() => {
            this.setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
            this.barCodeRead = true;
          }}
        >
          <Text style={{ alignSelf: "center", color: "#FF0000" }}>Skanna</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
  </View>
</Modal>
```

Comment: @AjeetShah Yea i forgot to add that but it's still complaining about the same error

Comment: I have fixed that as u can see updated code above^^  still the same error

Comment: I don't understand why my answer didn't work for you. I would suggest one *change* in my answer - `this.barCodeRead` should be moved to state var so that it reads `this.state.barCodeRead` so that UI will re-render (update) when it changes.

Comment: @AjeetShah Can u show me on github? easier to understand that way

Comment: I will retry if possible. I was trying but React Native Camera itself wasn't working due to configuration issue (I'm new to React Native).

Comment: Follow the steps and it should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Fixed it by myself. By just taking a pause from the project, I realized how easy it was to fix the problem.

```
this.state = {
      modalVisible: false,
      company: [],
      name: [],
      gluten: [],
      ingredients: [],
      id: [],
}

checkBarcode(scanResult) {
    const product = DataBase.find((codeMetadata) => {
      return codeMetadata.id === scanResult.data;
    });

    if (this.barCodeRead) {
      if (product) {
        this.barCodeRead = false;
        this.setState({
          modalVisible: true,
          company: [product.company],
          name: [product.name],
          gluten: [product.gluten],
          ingredients: [product.ingredients],
          id: [product.id],
        });
      } else {
        
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to return some [JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html) from render function in your components. If you want to show nothing at the UI, you can return `null`. An example:

```
if (this.barCodeRead) {
  if (product) {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{product.company}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Produkten finns inte</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
 }
 return <div>No Data to show</div> // or null
```

Comment: By doing this the only text to be shown in the modal will be for example no data to show. it's working fine when i use alert.alert but i want something nicer than the ugly alert

Comment: Still the same and btw `this.barCodeRead` is only for stopping the barcode scanner to scan more than once and. I have `this.barCodeRead = true` above the this.state.

Comment: No it's still the same problem. Here is the pastebin for full code: https://pastebin.com/ZiWHzNLf

Comment: I have added an issue on github and lets take the conversation there

Answer (score 1):

Have a try with the below code changes as you have to return JSX or null if the barCodeRead has nullish value

```
CheckBarcode(scanResult) {
    const product = DataBase.find((codeMetadata) => {
      return codeMetadata.id === scanResult.data;
    });

    if (this.barCodeRead) {
      if (product) {
        this.barCodeRead = false;
        this.setModalVisible(true);
        return (
          <View>
            <Text>{product.company}</Text>
            <Text>{product.name}</Text>
            <Text>{product.gluten}</Text>
            <Text>{product.ingredients}</Text>
            <Text>{product.id}</Text>
          </View>
        );
      } else {
        this.barCodeRead = true;
        return (
          <View>
            <Text>Produkten finns inte</Text>
          </View>
        );
      }
    } else {
      return (
        <View>
          <Text>No product</Text>
        </View>
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: The modal shows up like it should but if i scan a barcode that i know is in my database its just displaying No Product. But if i use Alert.alert its working fine and its displaying the right product from the database???

Comment: Can you please try with console.log(product). to check that the product is available or not?

Comment: yes its showing the right product in console

Comment: can you also check the value for this.barCodeRead by console.log(this.barCodeRead) ?

Comment: Its showing true and false like it should

Comment: but actually i want to know the value of it you got as if it has falsy then you always see the No Product in modal.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230840/discussion-between-lmao12233-and-jignesh-mayani).